# ¿Existe redundancia de datos en la tabla de "cursos"?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Soy estudiante y para mi proyecto final he decidido crear un sistema de gestión para una institución educativa de mi barrio. Mi profesor me señaló que en la tabla "Cursos" existe excesiva redundancia de datos pero planteando desde 0 me parece la solución más óptima en base a mi planteamiento.

**Planteamiento:**

El sistema debe permitir el registro de alumnos a los cursos existentes en el año lectivo en curso, si no existe año lectivo, permitir su creación y la de los cursos para ese año lectivo.

**Análisis:**

1. La inscripción es el proceso principal
2. Para que exista una inscripción es necesario que exista:

   1. Alumnos
   2. Cursos
3. Los cursos a su vez, no pueden existir sin que antes la institución habilite un nuevo año lectivo. Esto debido a que cada comienzo de año, las instituciones evalúan sus capacidades para definir si habilitan más o menos cursos.

**Diseño final:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle es que necesitas tablas de grados y secciones para que la tabla de cursos solo contenga sus IDs como ya lo hace con el ID de calendario. Esto es para evitar tener que almacenar el nombre de grados y secciones múltiples veces en la misma tabla. Además de que hace más fácil cambios a los mismos.